# PHP:CHECK record availbility SQL

Tags: php, encryption

So i have this php code,it is meant to encrypt a users password... Three problems/questions:

1. My 'salt' CHANGES ITS NAME;
2. I get the same result
3. Is this actually how the result is meant to be???

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php 
$password=$_POST['password'];
?>


<?php
if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1)
{
echo "Blowfish: ".crypt("$password",'$2a$09$anexamplestringforsalt$'); 
}
?>
```

**RESULT**

`Blowfish: $2a$09$anexamplestringforsaleU79j3Xck4QHAVNZ.exkIn8ZZrZnIrHq`

AS you can see, my salt goes from $anexamplestringforsalt$ to $anexamplestringforsaleU (or is that supposed to happen?) also,that is the same result I get even after changing the password

Please help

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords mate, hash them. And use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.password-hash.php), it's specifically make for this.

Comment: _Side note:_ There's no reason to pass variables in quoted strings. Instead of: `someFunction("$password", ...`, just do `someFunction($password, ...`

Comment: Can you explain these three "problems/questions" further? I don't get what you mean by the first and second point

Comment: @Andrew but php.net said  I shouldn't

Comment: Where does php.net say to not use `password_hash()` for hashing passwords?  While `crypt()` _does_ return a hash (not an encryption, despite what the name make make some people thing), `password_hash()` is preferred.